# Python Time limit for wait message

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Hello below code is working fine when we use `!ping` command bot asks first `Question 1` then if members types anything then bot asks for second `Question 2`

but if user not types anything then bot waits for `timeout = 30 seconds` and tells `Expired` and goes for asking next Question. So how to make bot stops after that it tells `Expired` when user not types anything.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Question 1")
    answer1 = await bot.wait_for_message(timeout= 30, author=ctx.message.author, channel=ctx.message.channel)
    if answer1 is None:
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Expired.")

    await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Question 2")
    answer2 = await bot.wait_for_message(timeout= 30, author=ctx.message.author, channel=ctx.message.channel)
    if answer2 is None:
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Expired.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `return` out of a coroutine just like a regular function:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Question 1")
    answer1 = await bot.wait_for_message(timeout= 30, author=ctx.message.author, channel=ctx.message.channel)
    if answer1 is None:
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Expired.")
        return
    await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Question 2")
    answer2 = await bot.wait_for_message(timeout= 30, author=ctx.message.author, channel=ctx.message.channel)
    if answer2 is None:
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Expired.")
        return
```